# accordion menu in aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I have this accordion working using just pure css with html: https://jsfiddle.net/11wunqqz/6/

but the problem is when I tried insert it in a aurelia code did not work.

reason? I am using href='#accordion' to make it work.

```
<a href="#accordion1" id="open-accordion1" title="open">First Accordion</a>
```

so when I click redirects me to the age localhost/#/accordion1

someone know best way to fix it? thank you

Comment: Why are you using anchor tags in the first place? If you don't want them to redirect somewhere, you should look into using a `button` or a `span` instead.

Comment: why? I don't know sorry, could help me to make it works in aurelia? thank you

Comment: I don't see the use of the `<a href>` in this scenario, have you tried changing it to a `span` so the application doesn't redirect you?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add **data-toggle="collapse" and data-parent** to that anchor element. It will resolve your issue.

or else remove anchor tag and add replace with span element.